# What colors stimulate learning

Tags: color, color-theory

What colorschemes do you think stimulate learning and attention seeking without being distracting?

Comment: You see one now...

Comment: This is an avenue of thinking which leads to death, destruction, and empty checkbooks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a magic color combination for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-researched area of pedagogy. Take a look at this article: http://www.excellence.dgs.ca.gov/MaxStPerformance/S4_4-2.htm

The psychosocial effects section will be of most interest to you as it is a condensed overview of some of the most well established findings on color and learning.

Answer (score 5):

Your first problem is that "learning" and "attention seeking" are somewhat at odds. If your color scheme is trying to get attention, by definition it's distracting, and you aren't going to be able to concentrate as well (and thereby learn).

If you want something not distracting, a clean, light-colored background (white, off-white, light beige, light gray) with a low-contrast color for a highlight (black, gray, navy blue, hunter green — not red) is somewhere to start.